# Number of Roots of a Polynomial is Bounded by its Degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Most of the textbooks state that provided a nonzero field $F$, a nonzero polynomial $f\in F[x]$ of degree $n$ has at most $n$ *distinct* roots. I am wondering whether the word "distinct" can be removed? I guess the answer is yes, but I cannot come up with a nice proof.

Sorry for the confusion. The question above can be rephrased as "if $f$ has roots $\alpha_i$ of multiplicity $n_i$, then is it possible that $\sum n_i>n$?"

Here $\alpha$ is of multiplicity $k$ means $(x-\alpha)^k\mid f$ but $(x-\alpha)^{k+1}\nmid f$.

For commutative ring this is possible, e.g, $x^2-x\in\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$ has roots $\overline{0},\overline{1},\overline{3},\overline{4}$.

Comment: The definition of multiplicity is that $\alpha$ has multiplicity $d$ if $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^d g(x)$ with $g(\alpha) \neq 0$.

Comment: @AlanMuniz see my definition.

Comment: suppose that sum were greater than n.  Then write it like you did before, into separate factors.  You will then see that expanding the product gives a polynomial (= f ) of degree greater than n, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @JalapenoNachos we can do the same thing for my counterexample. I think we will need to at least use the fact that $F[x]$ is a UFD.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing you need is that these are no non-trivial zero divisors, so that if $ab=0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$. So the formula for maximum number of roots works if you are working within a domain (and not just a field - the integers will do too).

Then you can use the polynomial division algorithm with $x-a$ to give, for any polynomial $p(x)$, that $$p(x)=(x-a)q(x)+r$$If you now make $a$ a root of $p$ and set $x=a$ you get $r=p(a)=0$ and $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)$. Then if $q(x)$ has a root $b$ you can take out a factor $x-b$ so you get $$p(x)=(x-a)^h(x-b)^t \dots (x-f)^us(x)$$ where $s$ has no roots, and may be a scalar.

Now, because there are no zero divisors, if $p(y)=0$ one of the factors must be zero. It can't be $s(y)$ ($s$ has no roots) so it must be one of the others, and so $y$ must be one of the roots you already know. Now equate degrees (or work the other way and use induction on degree).

In the case of integers modulo $6$ you have $2\times 3 \equiv 0$ so that $x(x-1)\equiv 0$ can be true even if $x$ is not $1$ or $2$.

Indeed we also have $x(x-1)\equiv (x-4)(x-3)$, which shows that factorisation is not unique.

Comment: I guess the step we need is that given $g,h\in F[x]$ with $gh\equiv0$ we need to conclude that $g\equiv0$ or $h\equiv0$. However, this fails. For example, take $F=\mathbb{F}_2$, and consider $x(x-1)\equiv0$. Of course, we don't have $x\equiv0$ nor $x-1\equiv0$.

Comment: I think you are moving too fast from $(x-a)^2\mid f=(x-a)q$ to $q=(x-a)q_1$. What we would get is $(x-a)^2p=f=(x-a)q$ and so $(x-a)[q-(x-a)p]=0$. But this does not imply $q-(x-a)p=0$.

Comment: @Easy In that case the polynomial is a quadratic. It factors into two factors and has at most two roots. If $p(x)=x^2-x$ and everything lives in $\mathbb F_2$ then $p(0)=p(1)=0$ but we don't have $p(x)=0$. I haven't said $p(x)=0$ in this case, simply that $p(x)$ has at most two linear factors and therefore (because no zero divisors) at most two roots.

Comment: I think we need to define what it means by "=" in $F[x]$. By "$f\equiv g$" we mean $f,g$ return the same value for every input $x$. So in form of symbols, we do have $p(x)\neq0$, but indeed we have $p(x)\equiv0$. However, it seems to me the latter one is what we really by "=" here. In fact, given $p(x)=x^2-x$, one can also write $p(x)=(x^2-x)^2$, neither contradicts to Factor Theorem.

Comment: Anyway, I think the most thing here is how you can explain my second comment for the step moving for $f=(x-a)q$ to $f=(x-a)^2q_1$.

Comment: @Easy At each stage I identify a root and divide through by a linear polynomial, then factor the quotient. If the quotient has a root I have already found, then I get a multiple factor in the factorisation. I can't have more than $n$ linear factors because of the degree. Some of the linear factors may represent multiple roots. If I get to a quotient with no linear factors I may have fewer than $n$ roots. Two polynomials are equal if they are equal as polynomials. I think you are overcomplicating things.

Comment: I still don't see how you can get a multiple factor. In usual case we identify the polynomials by their expression is because they are unique over the ring. However, this does not apply to all fields.

Comment: I think you need to be careful about the word "divide" here, as the cancellation law  of polynomials might not hold.

Comment: @Easy I am not sure what you mean by "the cancellation law of polynomials". Note that $(x^2-x)^2=x^2(x-1)^2$ has a perfectly good factorisation of the form I have suggested and has four roots "with multiplicity" and two roots without. Both figures are $\le 4$ which is the order of the original polynomial.

Comment: @Easy Over a finite field a polynomial may not be determined by its values - two different polynomials may take the same values for each element of the field. That does not mean that they are the same polynomial, and indeed they may take different values for different elements of some extension field. You may also be interested in inseparable extensions/polynomials, which I won't explain here. Since all my divisions are by polynomials which are monic of degree $1$ I don't see any problem in carrying out the divisions I need. It is a lot simpler than you are trying to make it.

Comment: You can have a look at here for what I mean by "cancellation law": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910584/fx-is-a-domain/2910594?noredirect=1#

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\alpha$ were not a root of g.

Then $\alpha$ is a simple root of f, which is a contradiction.