# $F[x]$ is a domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Given a field $F$, the ring of polynomials $F[x]$ is a popular example of ED. However, it seems that $F[x]$ does not even have to be a domain.

For example, take $F=\mathbb{F}_2$. Then
$$x(x-1)\equiv0$$
since LHS and RHS always have the same output for whatever input $x$. But of course we don't have $x\equiv0$ nor $x-1\equiv0$, which shows that zero divisor exists. How can we explain this?

Comment: For an infinite field, there is a one-to-one correspondence between polynomials and polynomial functions. For finite fields, this does not hold.

Comment: @Wuestenfux If so, then why people still regard $F[x]$ as a ED, as it is even NOT a domain! Or they consider this in a different sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomial $x^2-x$ is identically $0$ on $F$, but it is not equal to $0$ in $F[x]$. Your issue is confusing equality of functions with equality of polynomials. Remember that two polynomials are equal if and only if all of their coefficients are equal. Whereas, two functions on the same sets are equal if and only if they agree everywhere.

Comment: Yes, we identify polynomials by their expressions as we define so. But in set of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, do we really distinguish $x^2-x$ and $0$?

Comment: We distinguish between $x^2−x$ and $0$ in $F[x]$ for precisely the same reason that we distinguish between $(0,0,0,0,0,…)$ and $(0,−1,1,0,0,…)$ in the set of all sequences of members of $F$.

Comment: One can check that all results of $F[x]$ about ED, PID, UFD still hold without this definition. I guess people make such a definition is because they can directly apply the results of ED, PID, UFD etc. Otherwise, this sounds very strange as it is just like $x^2-2x+1$ and $(x-1)^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ we call them different.

Comment: @Easy: A polynomial in $x$ over $\mathbb{F}$ is formally defined as a finitely-supported sequence $\left(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots\right)$ of elements of $\mathbb{F}$; those elements are called its coefficients. Then, addition and multiplication and $\mathbb{F}$-scalar multiplication of polynomials are defined. Then, $x$ is defined as the polynomial corresponding to the sequence $\left(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots\right)$ with exactly one $1$ between all the zeroes. Finally, it is ...

Comment: ... shown that each polynomial $\left(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots\right)$ is equal to the sum $a_0 x^0 + a_1 x^1 + a_2 x^2 + \cdots$ (which is a well-defined sum because all but finitely many $a_i$ are zero). This is the standard approach to defining polynomials, although it tends to fall through the cracks in undergraduate education. Both $x^2 - 2x + 1$ and $\left(x-1\right)^2$ are then equal to the polynomial $\left(1,-2,1,0,0,0,\ldots\right)$, by the rules for adding, subtracting and multiplying polynomials.

Comment: Recommended reading: Sections 7.1 to 7.3 of Nicholas Loehr, *Bijective Combinatorics*, 1st edition 2011. (The second edition is more confusing on this.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg The problem is not about the definition but about the actual usage.  For example, when we say $(x-a)^2$ divides $(x-a)g(x)$ in $F[x]$ we hope that $(x-a)$ divides $g(x)$. But we don't quite have this because this comes from that $(x-a)^2h(x)=(x-a)^2g(x)$ and so $(x-a)[(x-a)h(x)-g(x)]=0$ with the cancellation law holds. See here for the motivation of the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910301/number-of-roots-of-a-polynomial-is-bounded-by-its-degree

Comment: @Easy: The cancellation law does indeed hold, but only because polynomials are defined as sequences of coefficients! For polynomial *functions* it does not hold. For example, $x^2 \mid x\left(x+1\right)$ as polynomial *functions* over $\mathbb{F}_2$, but not $x \mid x+1$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg So it sounds like my proposal was not wrong in the other question? That is, the sum of multiplicity might be greater than the degree of a polynomial?

Comment: @Easy: No. Mark Bennet's proof is correct (when $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, or an integral domain).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Well, just take yours as an example. $f(x)=x(x+1)\in\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ of degree $2$. But the sum of multiplicity will be infinity!

Comment: @Easy: No, it won't be infinity. It will be $2$. There are two roots ($0$ and $1$), and each has multiplicity $1$ (since neither $x^2$ nor $\left(x-1\right)^2$ divides $f\left(x\right)$ **as a polynomial**).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Back to $(x-a)[(x-a)h-g]=0$, can you conclude that $(x-a)h-g=0$?

Comment: @Easy: Yes, because $x-a \neq 0$ as a polynomial.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Using this argument, you can also get $x(x+1)=0$ implies $x=0$ or $x+1=0$.

Comment: Yes, but $x\left(x+1\right) \neq 0$ as polynomials.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I still don't see the difference between these two. Can you tell?

Comment: $x\left(x+1\right) = \left(0,1,0,0,0,\ldots\right)\left(1,1,0,0,0,\ldots\right) = \left(0,1,1,0,0,\ldots\right)$, which is not the same as $0 = \left(0,0,0,0,0,\ldots\right)$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I think I know what the problem is now. What I started with $g(x)$ should be viewed as a polynomial but NOT a function.

Comment: Yes. Polynomials only act as functions when you substitute numbers in them; before that they're just sequences of coefficients.