# Why does this not preserve solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Start with
$$(x+4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16$$ and
$$2x^2 - 7x = x$$
We can subtract one from the other leaving us with
$$(x+4)^2 - (2x^2 -7x) =  x^2 + 7x + 16$$
and solve that like normal. But, if we substitute $2x^2 - 7x = x$, getting us
$$(2x^2 - 7x +4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16$$ we get an extra solution, $x = 3$.

How/Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x=3$ is not a solution of your final equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting $(x+4)^2$ as $x^2+8x+16$ is just a red herring.

No need to compare the number of roots and the degrees. What you wrote can be simply summarized as:
$$\begin{align}2x^2-7x=x&\iff2x^2-7x+4=x+4\\&\color{red}\implies(2x^2-7x+4)^2=(x+4)^2\\&\iff(x^2-3x+4)(2x^2-8x)=0\end{align}$$
i.e. by squaring, you introduced new solutions: the roots of $x^2-3x+4.$

Comment: What is the difference if we start with the $x+4$ already squared?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. No matter under which form you write $(x+4)^2.$ Rewriting it $x^2+8x+16$ or not makes no difference. The problem is not there.

Comment: Its because in your case you  are the one who did the squaring, does the exact same thing happen if you start with $(x+4)^2$ then sub $x$?

Comment: If I start with $a = b$ then squaring gets $a^2 = b^2$ then square rooting giver $a=b$ or $a=-b$ these are the cases when you do the squaring. I understand this. Is this identical to the approach where you start with $(x+4)^2$, even if you do not do the square rooting step explicitly?

Comment: *You* did the squaring. It was just hidden beind your substraction and substitution. Starting with $(x+4)^2=(x+4)^2$ ($=x^2+8x+16$ but this is irrelevant), substracting $2x^2-7x$ on both sides just obscures the point. What you did was essentially substituting $x$ with $2x^2-7x$ on one side of $(x+4)^2=(x+4)^2,$ which amounts to "my" squaring.

Comment: Ok, and the weird arrow that points in both direction is an "if and only if" sign? Right?
Can we conclude that the identity must work for all $x$ such that $2x^2-7x = x$, but (the other two solutions, as its a quartic) cannot be deduced purely from the two statements that made up the identity (those being $(x+4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16 $ and $2x^2 - 7x = x$?

Comment: Yes, the (usual) symbol $\iff$ reads "if and only if", whereas $\implies$ reads "implies". Once again, $(x+4)^2=x^2+8x+16$ is irrelevant. Your proof, once skimmed, reduces to saying that the last identitiy in my answer holds indeed for every $x$ such that $2x^2-7x=x$ but the converse is false, because the red $\implies$ cannot be changed to an $\iff.$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Does that mean in general we cannot say that "if and only if $x = B(x)$" then $Q$ is true? (if $P$ is some statement we are substituting into), and we should say that "if $x=B(x)$ then it IMPLIES $Q$ is true? (if $Q$ is what we get after substituting $P$ with $x = B(x)$ in as many instances of $x$ as you want)

Comment: More precisely, if $Q$ is related to $P$ like you wrote, then: *for every $x$ such that $P$ is true*, we cannot say that $x=B(x)\iff Q$ but only that $x=B(x)\implies Q.$ E.g. if $P$ (and therefore also $Q$) is simply $\text{TRUE}$ then anything implies $Q$ but $Q$ does not imply anything.

Comment: Then it follows that it was my mistake thinking $Q$ was only TRUE if $x=B(x)$ was true which I now understand is rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the Fundamental theorem of algebra that says that polynomial equation of degree $n$ has $n$ complex solutions. The second equation you consider is of degree $4$, instead of original degree $2$.

To elaborate a bit more

$$ (x+4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16 \text{ and } 2x^2 - 7x = x \implies (2x^2 - 7x +4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16$$

but $$ (2x^2 - 7x +4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16 \quad\not\!\!\!\!\implies (x+4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16 \text{ and } 2x^2 - 7x = x.$$

To see why, rewrite $x^2+8x + 16$ as $(x+4)^2$. Then, $(2x^2 - 7x +4)^2 = (x+4)^2$ does not imply $2x^2 - 7x +4 = x+4$, for the same reason $x^2 = 2^2$ does not imply $x=2$, but rather $x = \pm 2$.

Instead, $(2x^2 - 7x +4)^2 = (x+4)^2$ is equivalent to $2x^2 - 7x +4 = x+4 \text{ or } 2x^2 - 7x +4 = -(x+4)$. The first has solutions $x =0,4$ and the second has solutions $x = \frac{3\pm i \sqrt 7}2$.

Comment: While I agree @Ennar could have elaborated, this is still correct! What is wrong with MathSE? Why is this answer getting so many downvotes?

Comment: @NavBhatthal, I'm sorry, what? Fundamental theorem of algebra is wrong? $2x^2 - 7x = x$ has two solutions , $0$ and $4$, $(x+4)^2 - (2x^2 -7x) =  x^2 + 7x + 16$ has two solutions, $0$ and $4$ and $(2x^2 - 7x +4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16$ has four solutions, $0$, $4$ and $1/2(3\pm i\sqrt 7)$.  I don't know how did three clueless people manage to read this answer in such a short time, but I am not wrong.

Comment: I think its because you said it has $n$ complex solutions, not just $n$ solutions. (Which can be real and complex)

Comment: @NavBhatthal $\mathbb R\subseteq \mathbb C$. All real numbers are complex.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer then. However my question still holds, when I substitute $x= 2x^2 - 7x$, am I not stating "the next line is only true when $x = 2x^2 - 7x$?

Comment: @Nav Bhatthal, $(2x^2 - 7x +4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16$ has four solutions because of Fundamental theorem of algebra, the system $(2x^2 - 7x +4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16, x = 2x^2 - 7x$ has two solutions. When you square something, you introduce extra solutions because squaring is not injective function. For example, $x = 2$ has one solution, and when we square it, we get $x^2 = 4$ which has two solutions. I would ask you politely to retract your downvote now, because this is ridiculous.

Comment: You say that squaring is what causes the extra solutions, but I can make other substitutions in the form $x = ax^2 + bx$ and have the solutions to the substituted polynomial be the solutions to $x = ax^2 + bx$, is there something very specific which makes the final equation have extra solutions? Thanks.

Comment: @NavBhatthal, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to check the remaining
equation actually holds and this bounds the number of solutions of the system over an algebraically closed field to 2 since it is quadratic.

Edit: The bound actually holds for rings with no non trivial zero divisors as proved here [Number of Roots of a Polynomial is Bounded by its Degree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910301/number-of-roots-of-a-polynomial-is-bounded-by-its-degree)

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Thank you for answering.

Comment: Your statement is I have a system of 2 equations and I can modify the first equation by either substituting expressions you can deduce from the second or substracting the second. This will lead to an equivalent system of equations, but it won't allow you to collapse the system to one equation.

Comment: For instance, if you consider the system given by equations $x=1$ and $x^4+1=2x$ you could substitute in the right hand side of the second equation $x$ for 1 giving $x^4+1=2$. The system still has only one solution, (x=1), but the second equation we can find 4 solutions over the complex numbers.

Comment: The comment on algebraically closed fields is just because it was the first condition I thought of that guarantees we are in a "nice" ring probably works on any field, but there are rings where there can be more solutions for instance $2x=0$ has  four solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$.